# GIT: Command for overwriting all conflicting files from Current branch with Feature branch on merge

Tags: git, version-control, merge, git-branch, git-merge

I am getting a conflict with merging my "feature" branch into my "current" branch and would like to know the easiest way to tell git to proceed by ignoring the merge conflict in the listed files and overwrite the files (...file1.ext, file2.ext...) on the "current" branch with the files on the "feature" branch. I am not interested in looking at the actual contents of the files through a text editor to see where the conflict is occurring. I simple want to run a GIT command that overwrites them with their new versions on the "feature" branch and gives me a new "current" branch with the changes from "feature". I've run the following so far:

git checkout current
git merge feature

After the merge is run I get these conflict messages. How should I proceed?

```
...    
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in path/to/file1.ext
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in path/to/file2.ext
...
```

Comment: If it is a small number of files take a look at the `--ours` and `--theirs` options to `git checkout`

Comment: so in this context, I would use git checkout --theirs path/to/file1.ext for the first conflict?

Comment: Presuming you want to overwrite their changes yes.  Otherwise you would do `git mergetool` and pick and choose changes.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want to do is checkout feature, then merge current with the 'ours' merge strategy.  What this will do is ignore changes in current, and just create a new merge commit that is identical to feature but has ancestors of both current and feature. Both current and feature will now point to this commit.

```
git checkout feature
git merge -s ours current
```

Note that if you do this any changes you've made to current that are not in feature are ignored from then on.

If on the other hand you want to do a real merge with what is in current, but always favor changes from feature when there is a conflict, you can do it like this:

```
git checkout current
git merge -Xtheirs feature
```

This will do a regular merge, but instead of making you do manual conflict resolution it will always take changes from feature.  However, if their are "real" conflicts this could result in broken code in the merged files.